# Jquery form submit losing form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have this form which is supposed to send the info to the database for a username search. I'm putting together a search function for private servers in our student dormitory. We have a dude with username `<lol>` and it seems we can't search him. Other usernames search just fine. I'm I missing something?

This is the form.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkForm').validate({
    rules: {
    IpSearch: {
    ipv4:true,
    require_from_group: [1, ".required_group"]
    },
    UserName: {
    minlength: 3,
    require_from_group: [1, ".required_group"]
    }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    console.log( $("#checkForm").serialize());
    $('#results').text( $("#checkForm").serialize());
    $.post('file.php', $("#checkForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#checkResult').html(data);

    });
    }
    });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>


                    <form role="form" id="checkForm" name="checkForm" method="post">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Internal IP:</label>
                          <input id="IpSearch" name="IpSearch" placeholder="Enter IP" class="form-control optional required_group" type="text">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Username</label>
                          <input id="UserName" name="UserName" value="<?php if(!empty ($_POST) && isset($_POST['checkThis'])){echo $_POST['checkThis']; } else{}?>" placeholder="admin" class="form-control optional defaultInvalid required_group" type="text">
                       </div>
                       <button id="search" name="search" value="doSearch" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                    </form>


<div id="results"></div>
<div id="checkResult"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the file.php beginning:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
// .... continues but irrelevant since I'm not getting any post data
```

On clicking the button, I get this in browser console:

```
"IpSearch=&UserName=%3Clol%3E&search=doSearch"
```

on #results I get: 
    IpSearch=&UserName=%3Clol%3E&search=doSearch

on #checkResult I get:

```
array(3) {
  ["IpSearch"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["UserName"]=>
  string(5) ""
  ["search"]=>
  string(8) "doSearch"
```

}

Comment: Sorry I misread I didnt see printed in Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't show `<lol>` because it considered HTML tag when jquery print it.

you must escape html entities before printing it.

so change this line: `$('#checkResult').html(data);` to `$('#checkResult').text(data);`

so this will print `<lol>` as text not html

Answer (score 0):

Try vardumping $_GET 
    `var_dump($_GET)` 
And post results here :) 
Looks like your script doesn't prevent default action and form gets submitted anyway

Comment: that was `var_dump($_GET)` instead of `var_dump($_POST)` as posted in the question.